# Google sheets formula to add order quantities over several sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

here is a link to my google sheet for reference: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tUlqB2tsH4xEsxYiMv1CiUIY3hhLGpM-1G8eWOyZPWk/edit?usp=sharing]

What I am trying to do is in the "Clients" sheet there is the column "Orders". Here I want a count of all the times that "Client ID" has been used across all the other pages. Any tips on what formula to use? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
={"Orders";ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="","",COUNTIF({Jun!B:B;July!B:B;August!B:B;Sept!B:B}, A2:A)))}
```

Answer (score 1):

from what i saw you only needed to add the ARRAYFORMULA to your formula, it should end up like this: `=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF({Jun!B:B;July!B:B;August!B:B;Sept!B:B},A2))`.

But, even after adding it, to me at least, the results didn't change. Could you verify and make sure there's a problem with the results the SUMIFS is giving you?

If you find anything that's broken I'll try and help.